# Передача списка в функцию: по ссылке или по значению?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, типы-данных, аргументы

Из следующего примера выходит, что по ссылке:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def my_function(values):
    values.append('d')
    print(values)
```

при вызове `my_function` с `my_list` в качестве аргумента,
ожидаемо видим вывод на печать списка из четырех элементов:

```
>>> my_function(my_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

и измененный `my_list`:

```
>>> print(my_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Но если сделать так:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def my_function(values):
    values = ['d', 'e']
    print(values)
```

то выходит, что по значению:

```
>>> my_function(my_list)
['d', 'e']
>>> print(my_list)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Как, все таки, изменяемые типы передаются в функцию в качестве аргументов?

Comment: В первом примере вы изменяет полученный список, а во втором создаётся новый который никак не связан с `my_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В переменной `values` у вас получается ссылка на переданный список. И когда вы в этот список что-то добавляете внутри функции, то данные добавляются в исходный список, на который указывает переменная.

Однако, если вы присвоите внутри функции переменной `values` ссылку на новый список, это никак не повлияет на тот список, который был передан в функцию - переменная `values` существует только внутри функции и после такого присвоения она просто потеряет всякую связь с исходным списком.

Это в общем-то так с любыми переменными внутри функции - когда вы им что-то присваиваете, это никак не влияет на те переменные, которые были переданы в функцию. Скорее наоборот тут несколько удивительно, что вы можете менять список, ссылка на который была передана в функцию. Но это именно благодаря тому, что в переменной находится не сам список, а ссылка на него.

Answer (score 4):

В первом примере вы изменяет полученный список, а во втором создаётся новый который никак не связан с `my_list`

пример:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def my_function(values):
    values.append('d')
    return values

print(my_list is my_function(my_list))
```

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def my_function(values):
    values = ['d', 'e']
    return values

print(my_list is my_function(my_list))
```

в первом случае `my_list` и результат функции это один объект, а во втором два разных